# Low rep users should be able to make comments

Tags: discussion, support

If low rep users can ask a question and can answer a question, why can't they comment on an answer?

Comment: Because comments are more open to abuse and not as heavily regulated. How hard is it to get the few rep points to comment? You could have done it in the time it took you to think up this question....

Comment: @Magisch - Thanks for your response.  But honestly it can take a considerably number of hours to earn 50 rep points, or maybe I'm missing something.  Please tell, how is it that I can earn 50 rep points in the time it takes to think up a questions? (said out of frustration)

Comment: Write a good question or Answer. 50 points is 5 upvotes on an answer or 10 on a question.

Comment: @Magisch - Thanks, that's helpful, I was concerned I needed to accumulate 50 up votes.  Can you provide a link to a page that explains the points system?  Also, now that this questions has -13 for in down votes, how will that impact my ability to earn 50 points so that I can comment?

Answer (score 2):

As I remember, it is possible to comment answers for you own question.

Comment: This is true and quite helpful.  Thanks!